# nodejs how to call a function again when it finishes

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Let's say I have a function,

```
function hello(){
  console.log('hello world');
}
```

Now I want to call this function again, as soon as it finishes. So I do something like this:

```
function hello(){
  console.log('hello world');
  hello();
}
```

However, doing this does not work as expected, because due to the asynchronous nature of nodejs, `hello` is called again before `console.log('hello world');` finishes executing.

Is there a way to run the function `hello` repeatedly, but wait until it finishes before it runs for a second time?

Comment: `However, doing this does not work as expected, because due to the asynchronous nature of nodejs,  hello is called again before console.log('hello world'); finishes executing.` - That doesn't make sense considering nodejs's asynchronous nature would still execute that function as expected. Are you using promises in your code, async functions? I suspect you're attempting to replicate a problem that isn't apparent in your example.

Comment: It sounds like you are infinitely looping a function with no true exit condition, and are exhausting the stack.

Comment: [Here's a jsfiddle of your example](https://jsfiddle.net/g33yf0d7/), and yes, testing in nodejs produces the same result.

Comment: @eeze you need some condition that tells you when to stop calling the function over and over again.

Comment: My guess is that the code you show in your question is an oversimplification that you made up to illustrate the problem and it doesn't actually illustrate the problem because there's no asynchronous operation there.

Comment: If your REAL code actually contains an asynchronous operation, then you HAVE to post the actual code for us to be able to help you appropriately.  The real answer is that you hook into the completion of the async operation and you call the function again only when the async operation notifies its completion.  How to do that exactly depends upon the nature of the async operation so we have to see that code to help you in more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. Rather, it's that you have an infinite recursion and that quickly causes a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` to protect you from consuming all of a machines memory with a giant stack of function calls.

You are not required to have a stopping condition. You can actually use the asynchronous nature of JavaScript to fix it:

```js
function hello(){
  console.log('hello world');
  setTimeout(hello, 0);
}

hello();
```